# Duplicate items in std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, std, stdmap

There's a certain piece of code in our product which uses an std::map to store data, the key for which is boost::make_tuple(std::string, std::string). While debugging an issue, I found that after inserting a key-value pair in the map, find for that key in the map resulted in negative, and another attempt to insert the key-value1 pair succeeded.

This illustrates the sequence of operations:

```
Flow A:

Key k = boost::make_tuple(str1, str2);
bool added = temp_map_.insert(std::make_pair(k, val)).second;

Flow B:

TempMap::iterator itr = temp_map_.find(k);
if (itr == temp_map_.end()) {
    Key k = boost::make_tuple(str1, str2);
    bool added = temp_map_.insert(std::make_pair(k, val1)).second;
}
```

Please note that Flow B begins after Flow A is completed.

The first 'insert' succeeds. The 'find' does not find the key, and the second 'insert' also succeeds. Eventually, the 'erase' operation on the key succeeds, and the subsequent 'find' finds the key in the map.

I don't have a reproducer for this, but this happens in our product when a certain test is run repeatedly, say about 6-7 times.

Any thoughts on how this can happen?

Comment: Sorry if too obvious: Is the map constructed with a custom (broken) comparator?

Comment: And sure that str1 and str2 are both std::string ?

Comment: You say that you do the insert if `find` does not succeed. But the code in your question states otherwise. The if statement should be `if (itr == temp_map_.end())`.

Comment: @Marco13: Yes, it uses a custom comparator. But this code is hit many, many times, but the problem is seen rarely.

Comment: @pschill: Thanks! I corrected the code.

Comment: *"the problem is seen rarely"* That may just mean that the comparator is broken in a subtle way. "Seems to work most of the time, breaks rarely" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior. Another possibility: is there any multi-threading in play? "Breaks rarely in a way that's difficult to reproduce" is a hallmark of data races.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: The thread of execution in Flow A is completed before Flow B starts. So, race condition can be ruled out.

Comment: @Maddy did fixing the typo actually solve the problem? (Then you may delete the question or self-answer instead of 'fixing' it in the question body...)

Comment: @moooeeeep: It was a typo at the time of posting the question. The problem persists. I'm checking if there are issues with the comparator.

Comment: Post the comparator?